# Hiding an Icon in MenuItem when Source is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, menuitem

I'm trying to hide the `Icon` space of a `MenuItem` when the `Source` is null (not specified).

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.  If the `IconSource` is not specified, I dont want the spacing that is left behind by an empty `Icon`

Currently:

[image: Currently]

Desired:

[image: Desired]

The following is the Menu xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MenuBarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="MenuItemIcon" Source="{Binding IconSource, TargetNullValue={x:Null}}"
               Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelWidth}" 
               Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelHeight}" 
               x:Shared="False"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MenuItems}" />
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I think you have to copy and modify the default template of `MenuItem`. In fact there is a Grid column reserved for the `Icon`, this Grid column has `MinWidth` hardcodedly set to `24`. We have no way to change this value from outside the template.

Comment: @KingKing - I was hoping there was an easier way, since if you remove the `Setter` for the `Icon` in the `Style`, there is no gap and it produces the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what I said in my comment is true but for Sub MenuItem, for Top-level menu item, all the components are placed in a `DockPanel`, and in fact when the `Icon` is null, it will be collapsed (there is already a trigger in the default style doing this, so you don't have to add your own). The default icon placeholder has a Margin of `"4,0,6,0"`. That's why there is always a space when the `Icon` is not null (even the element set to `Icon` is collapsed).

That means we have no way to collapse the `ContentPresenter` (the Icon placeholder) unless we set `Icon` to `null`. In this case you can try setting `Icon` to `null` when the Source is null using a `DataTrigger` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
   <!-- ... -->
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IconSource,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}"
                   Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: +1 That did it, triggering on the `IconSource` when the value is `Null` and setting the `Icon` property to `Null` took care of it.  I dont need the `TargetNullValue` anymore either.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 yes, `TargetNullValue` here may set Image's `Source` to null, not replacing `Image` itself with null.